# Reduce opacity of a div in a horizontal scroll is it's partially visible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web-frontend

I am creating a carousel using HTML and CSS, which looks like this:

[image: Horizonral Scrollable Carousel]

Below is the Code:

```js
//It checks whether a card is outside the viewport ):

const box = document.querySelector(".card");
const rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log(rect);

function isInViewport() {
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <=
    (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

const result = isInViewport(box);
console.log(result);
document.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  function() {
    console.log(result);
  }, {
    passive: true,
  }
);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 415px;
  width: 1455px;
  padding-left: 150px;
}

.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 351px;
  width: 276px;
  border: 1px solid #dddbdb;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.card-img {
  height: 147px;
  width: 275px;
}

.card-head>p {
  height: 75px;
  width: 218px;
  color: #a72b2a;
  font-family: ".SF NS Display";
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: -0.33px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.card-body {
  height: 50px;
  width: 233px;
  color: #535353;
  font-family: ".SF NS Display";
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: -0.23px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.card-footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 28px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: ".SF NS Display";
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img"></div>
    <div class="card-rectangle">
      <div class="card-head">
        <p>
          Infographic: Understanding the basics and opportunity of hydrogen
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          There is no silver-bullet sustainable energy solution; a net zero future will…
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div>
          <p>12/11/20</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>|</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Kelly Jiang</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to reduce the opacity of a div whenever it is partially visible. (It could be in the extreme left or extreme right) (For example - one at the extreme right)
How can I do that?

Comment: Is this bulma, or am I wrong?

Comment: No, it's just CSS

Comment: The .card structure is very similar to the .card structure bulma uses :) Do you want to apply the entire opacity to the .card, if that card is out of view, or only part of the .card, using the gradient principle?

Comment: I want to apply to the entire .card if it's partially out of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I finally came up with which pretty much met my needs:

Added a new inactive class which changes the opacity of the card when applied:

```
.card-inactive {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Using JS added .card-inactive whenever a card is out of the viewport.

```
const card = document.getElementsByClassName("card"); //grabs all the elements with .card class
const container = document.getElementsByClassName("second-container")[0]; //grabs the div with .second-container class

function isInViewport(el) {
  let result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    const rect = el[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    // console.log(i, el.length);
    result.push(
      rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.right <=
          (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    ); // checks whether a div with the .card class is out of the viewport and stores the value in result[]
  }
  return result; // returns an array of boolean values for each element with .card class
}

container.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  //listens to scroll event inside second-container
  const result = isInViewport(card);
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // Below code adds/removes .card-inactive class
    if (!result[i]) {
      card[i].classList.add("card-inactive");
    } else card[i].classList.remove("card-inactive");
  }
});
```